# Property is not triggered second time

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have 4 polygons

```
...
xmlns:cm="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
...
<Polygon cm:Message.Attach="
    [Event MouseEnter] = [Action OnMouseEnter($eventArgs)];
    [Event MouseLeave] = [Action OnMouseLeave($eventArgs)];
    [Event MouseDown]  = [Action OnMouseDown($eventArgs)]">
    <Polygon.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding Path=TooltipVisibility}" >
...
```

on my canvas.

TooltipVisibility code:

```
    public string TooltipVisibility {
        get {
            if (OtherObject.IsTooltipVisibility) {
                return "Visible";
            }
            else {
                return "Hidden";
            }
        }
    }
```

And IsTooltipVisibility on OtherObject is changed from 3rd place. I tried to execute `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => myObject.TooltipVisibility );`, I tried run `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => otherObject.IsTooltipVisibility);`.

The funny (however, not really) thing is that if I hover mouse on one polygon it shows tooltip, then I change IsTooltipVisibility (by hitting menu button in the menu bar) to false, it doesn't show tooltip on second polygon, but still shows it on the first one. Third one will not show tooltip. Change to true, 4th one will show, however, 2nd and 3rd won't.

The TooltipVisibility property executed just ones. How can I make it execute all the time?

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird solution. It works. Maybe it should work this way. But I think it's too complex. It should be more straightforward and with less code.

```
    public void SetTooltipVisibility(bool toShowTooltip) {
        if (toShowTooltip) {
            _tooltipVisibility = "Visible";
        }
        else {
            _tooltipVisibility = "Hidden";
        }
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TooltipVisibility);
    }

    private string _tooltipVisibility = "Visible";
    public string TooltipVisibility {
        get {
            return _tooltipVisibility;
        }
    }
```

And instead of just setting one flag

```
OtherObject.IsTooltipVisibility = true;
```

additionality I need to

```
liistOfMyObjects.Apply(o=>o.SetTooltipVisibility(OtherObject.IsTooltipVisibility));
```

Not the nicest solution.

I'm waiting for a PRO to show how this should be done in right manner.